# EF + UnitOfWork + SharePoint RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: entity-framework, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, impersonation

In our SharePoint application we have used the UnitOfWork + Repository patterns together with Entity Framework. To avoid the usage of the passthrough authentication we have developed a piece of code that impersonate a single user before creating the `ObjectContext` instance in a similar way that is described in "[Impersonating user with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1954944/431537)" on this site.

The only difference between our code and the referred question is that, to do the impersonation, we are using `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to impersonate the Application Pool identity as in the following sample.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { 
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url)) {
        _context = new MyDataContext(ConfigSingleton.GetInstance().ConnectionString);
    }
});
```

We have done this way because we expected that creating the `ObjectContext` after impersonation and, due to the fact that Repositories are receiving the impersonated `ObjectContext` would solve our requirement.

Unfortunately it's not so easy. In fact we experienced that, even if the `ObjectContext` is created before and under impersonation circumstances, the real connection is made just before executing the query, and so **does not use impersonation**, which break our requirement.

I have checked the `ObjectContext` class to see if there was any event through which we can inject the impersonation but unfortunately found nothing.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a simillar problem when we used LinqToSharePoint. The DataContext is created from the HttpContext.Current and did not consider the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method. We did a nasty workaround that we backed up the original HttpContext, created a new dummy HttpContext in the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method and the problem went away. Obviously we set the context to the original afterwards.

### Edit:

You can use the method below to create new dummy `HttpContext`.Call this method as first in your RunWithElevatedPrivileges. In the normal context just backup your currenct context with `var backupContext = HttpContext.Current` and after everything is done just set the context back.

```
private void SetNewContextWeb(SPWeb oWeb)   
{ 
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, oWeb.Url, string.Empty); 
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(httpRequest, new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StringWriter()));   
    SPControl.SetContextWeb(HttpContext.Current, oWeb);   
}
```

Comment: Can you please better detail your solution? Thanks