# Use Windows Auth in ASP.NET to access sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, user-permissions, database-permissions

is there a way to use windows accounts, that are logged into an web application, to use their credentials to access SqlServer, and use entity framework database first to execute various queries under their credentials?

Comment: yes....................lookup impersonation

Comment: Try this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1955003/707117